# How to delete row in quick edit using JsGrid?

Tags: sharepoint-online, quick-edit

how can I programmatically delete row in quick edit using JsGrid namespace? I know there's a method named DeleteRecords(), but probably I don't know how to use it properly. I tried to pass recordKey and it does nothing.

Thanks in advance,
Paweł

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far..

Comment: I want to add button which should delete row in quick edit. But as Max said Sharepoint Online doesn't support DeleteRecords() method. I will try with REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DeleteRecords()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff681038(v=office.14).aspx) applies to SharePoint Foundation 2010. SharePoint online isn't supported to use the method.

As a workaround, you can delete row via [REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-delete-a-list-in-sharepoint-2013-online-using-rest-ap/).

Comment: This explain all, thanks a lot. I will try with REST.